# How to chose which class to use when using both Bootstrap and MDBootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

Im not very proficient with CSS. I am using MDBootstrap for the majority of styling of my project, but  I really don't like it's `table` styling. I would like to use `table` CSS class from Bootstrap, not from MDB. In my template file I've added both dependencies

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/github-com-mdbootstrap-mdb-ui-kit/mdb.min.css}"/>
...
    <table class="table table-hover">
        ...
    </table>
...
```

And it uses `table` class from MDB. Is there a way to indicate that I want to use `<table class="table ...">` from ordinary Bootstrap?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The "from" only exists from your perspective here, but the browser does not differentiate that way.

Comment: Maybe you can include _just_ the table styling part of bootstrap, not the whole framework. The SASS version has individual include files for the different components, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/ If you are not using SASS in your project, then you could compile the relevant part to CSS once, and then embed the result from a static file.

Comment: Well this is possible if you create another page for table with the cdn of bootstrap you want then link it on the desire page using <iframe> tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with MDBootstrap is really quite identical to what you would do with Bootstrap itself. So all you really need to do is go to the GetBootstrap website to use their various CDN's.

This link will show you the info about how to lay out a table but check the *Overview* and *Getting Started* too, you will be up and running in a couple of minutes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/